# How to get a tableview's data in the background?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, delegates, background-process

I have a background task (usingParse.com API) that fetches and calculates the data for a tableview:

```
 var usedMessages = [String]()
 var currentMessages = [Message]()

func getCurrentMessages() {

 if currentUser != nil {
  var entryQuery = Entry.query()
  entryQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser)
  entryQuery.whereKey("originatedFromType", equalTo: "message")
  entryQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (entryObjects: [AnyObject]!, getEntriesError: NSError!) -> Void in

   for object in entryObjects {
    var entry = object as Entry
    usedMessages.append(entry.originatedFromId)
   }

   var messageQuery = Message.query()
   messageQuery.whereKey("endDate", greaterThan:NSDate())
   messageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    for object in objects {
     var message = object as Message
     if !contains(usedMessages, message.objectId) {
      currentMessages.append(message)
     }
    }
    self.tableview.reloadData()
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle fetching data for a tableview and then reloading the tableviews data? Or should I use a delegate that notifies the tableview that data has changed? or maybe even query.findObjectInBackgroundWithTarget and send the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always make sure that the reloadData and any **UI updates happen in the main thread**. Also check if the method does not return an error.

```
messageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if (error == nil)
    {
         //Your code.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    else
    {
        // Log the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you handled has no problem. But you have to make sure that is your desired behaviors. You basically fetch the data from **Entry** first, then fetch results from **Message** when the first call is finished. Then, you will reload the table view when the second call is done. There is not problems with that.

But, you have to check if there is an error returned and you might want to handle that if there are some certain errors you want to handle.